# Derived class VTable having only base class virtual functions. The derived class virtual functions are missing from derived class's vtable

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-studio-2012, polymorphism, vtable

Here is a very basic example:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void sayHi() const {}
    virtual void sayHello() {}
    virtual ~Base(){}
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual void sayHi() {}
    virtual void sayHello() const {}
};

int main()
{
    Base *b = new Base();
    Base *d = new Derived();
    return 0;
}
```

The Base's vptr, in 'b' has virtual functions of Base class. The derived class object 'd' however, on inspection, list virtual functions of only base.
The question here is **not**, why are the functions not being overridden so the use of override keyword isn't required here. The question is, why doesn't a particular class's VTable contain its own virtual functions? In this case why vtable of 'd' doesnt contain D::sayHi and D::sayHello?
I am open to downvotes, but be brave to mention and tell the reason.

edit:
**I know that the CONSTness might look wrong here, but the question is not about overriding.**

This is specifically tried out in VS2012 Update4

Comment: your const-ness is the wrong way around. Use the `override` keyword, and the compiler should tell you when you're not actually overriding what you think you are. For example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c8f303a8acbbc9d

Comment: it is explicitly mentioned in the question that this *question isn't about overriding*

Comment: Neither `Derived::sayHi` nor `Derived::sayHello` is virtual.

Comment: @T.C. thanks! added.

Comment: What is the question, really?

Comment: @curiousguy, the question is simply and clearly stated above. To be more clear, why the vtable inside 'd' doesnt have D::sayHi and D::sayHello? The VTable is supposed to have list of virtual functions. You can add anoher independent virtual function to Derived and that entry would also be not there in vtable of 'd'

Comment: The question is incomprehensible. I have read it four times, and I have no idea what you are trying to say. "_the vtable inside 'd'_" `d` is a pointer; there is no vtable in `d`. "_The VTable is supposed to have list of virtual functions_" the vtable contains pointers to the implementation of the overrider of a virtual function declaration. "_You can add anoher independent virtual function_" You can declare a new virtual function (that is not an overrider of another virtual function) "_that entry would also be not there in vtable_" source?

Comment: @curiousguy It feels like _you do not want to understand_. See people have posted correct answer!

Comment: @Abhinav Please don't make it personal. I am *not* writing that you don't want to make any effort to make your question clear.

Comment: Just because @Christophe correctly guessed you meant something about the debugger doesn't mean your question was sound. It wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have different function overloads that do not override the defined virtual functions:

```
virtual void sayHi() const {}
virtual void sayHello() {}

void sayHi() {}  // non virtual function with a different signature (no const)
void sayHello() const {} // non virtual function with a different signatuere (const)
```

If you want to avoid such subtle errors, use the keyword `override` : if the function that you think overrides a virtual function of the base class has a different signature or doesn't even exist (e.g.typo...) the compiler will generate an error.

**Edit following your edit:**

I see that you've updated the code to make the overloaded non overriding functions virtual as well.

Now the vtable of the derived function contains four distinct functions.  However, through the base pointer you can only access the virtual functions defined in the base. This is why the MSVC debugger shows you only 2:

[image]

By the way, the debugger seems to always show the vtable as a member of the Base.  But if you look at the assembler generated, you'll see the mangled names of all the virtual functions of the derived class in its vtable:

[image]

Comment: this isn't about overriding as mentioned in bold text. +edits to post

Comment: @Abhinav I suppose you say that there are only 2 functions because you look with the debugger.  I've made an edit to clarify

Comment: yes i looked in the debugger (i think you pasted screenshot of b rather than d ). Further i looked up the class layout with d1reportAllClassLayout and found what you were saying. Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to ask you if it would be considered a bug in VS debugger? If so, any known good debuggers?

Comment: For this code, it's not a bug, because he shows you only the vtable entries for the object corresponding to the pointer type.  However when you have a pointer to a derived (or a derived of derived), the debugger shows you the vtable under the Base subobject and again only the base functions appear.  This is more confusing. Nevertheless, the VS debugger is one of the best you can dream of.  You simply have to aknowledge that it's not the tool to use to explore vtables.

Comment: "_different function overloads_" the functions are declared in the derived class, with the same name but different signature, so they **hide** the base class functions

Answer (score 0):

Your Hi function does not override the base class Hi function as their const specifiers are wrong.
The same is true for your Hello functions, albeit the other way round.
If you use C++11 or later you can use the override keyword to make sure this doesn't happen.

Answer (score -1):

It was already mentioned that you are not overriding the functions as you are changing the functions signature by adding a const.

Concerning your actual questions:
It will use the vtable-pointer from the base class to point to its own vtable that has different entries. Thats just how it works. It "looks" like the base class but behaves "different". Thats polymorphic behaviour in C++.

If each deriving class would add its own vtable, a lot of things would be broken in C++. Multiple vtable pointers will only be part of an instance of a class, which derives from multiple classes containing virtual functions or when using virtual inheritance.

Comment: My dear friend Chris, each derived class will have it own VTable, derived from Base's vtable :)

Comment: No it does not have its own VTable in terms of a seperate vtable pointer in addition to the base class. It has an own vtable but uses the pointer from Base to point to it, if you meant that. Otherwise you ment something different. There was even a similar question asked here a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588993/why-derived-class-does-not-have-the-vtable-pointer-and-used-instead-vtable-of-th
If that still does not answer your questions, you did not describe your problem/concers properly.

Comment: I edited my answer though as it was a bit missleading: "It will use the vtable-pointer from the base class to point to its own vtable that has different entries."

Comment: Is there a need for VTable pointer to look 'like' base class? Doesnt seems correct. Although it can be said that the base will have a vptr, make it to point to the vtable of derived class.

Comment: Wrong: `struct B { virtual ~B(); int i; }; struct D : virtual B { }; `

Comment: Why would you use virtual inheritance when deriving from a single class?

Comment: Well although there is no reason (at least none I know) to do this, you are right: Just tried it out in VS, i edited my answer again. If you did the downvote, undo it again please. However, the author of this questions wont accept an answer anyway as it seems.

Comment: @Chris "_Why would you use virtual inheritance when deriving from a single class?_" the usual reason for using virtual inheritance: so that there is only one base class subobject of type `B` in some derived complete object

Comment: "_If each deriving class would add its own vtable, a lot of things would be broken in C++._" Please explain what you mean here.

Comment: Primarily I was only taking about the increase in size of each instance by an additional size_of(pointer_t) per hierarchy level on the given platform.